# Rails Chartkick. Multiple Series line chart with nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, charts, chartkick

Trying to do a multiple series line chart. (Visualizer is Chartjs.) From the `README`:

```
<%= line_chart [
  {name: "Series A", data: series_a},
  {name: "Series B", data: series_b}
] %>
```

My data is coming in JSON format already, but takes a little manipulation to get right. Raw form looks like this:

```
=> [{"id"=>30,
  "runner"=>"Golden State Warriors",
  "price"=>1.51,
  "histories"=>[{"price"=>1.51, "created_at"=>"2016-11-19T17:42:18.699Z"}, {"price"=>1.51, "created_at"=>"2016-11-20T07:56:55.662Z"}]},
 {"id"=>32, ETC
```

So, with
`markets.map{ |m| [name: m['runner'], data: m['histories'].map{|h| [h['created_at'], 1/h['price']] }]}.flatten!`
which yields:

```
=> [
{:name=>"Golden State Warriors", :data=>[["2016-11-19T17:42:18.699Z", 0.6622516556291391], ["2016-11-20T07:56:55.662Z", 0.6622516556291391]]},
{:name=>"Los Angeles Clippers", :data=>[["2016-11-19T17:42:18.795Z", 0.1], ["2016-11-20T07:56:55.717Z", 0.1]]}, ETC
```

Although I don't get an error, the chart is an empty quadrant with `[object Object]` at 0,0.

The chart is in an `@markets.each` block in my view because I want to create multiple charts the page showing the same thing with different data. I played around with an `.each_with_index` and I can get the chart to show partially by just manually inputting the data as the `README` shows:

```
<%= line_chart [
      {name: markets[i]['runner'], data: markets[i]['histories'].map{|h| [h['created_at'], 1/h['price']]}},
      {name: markets[i+1]['runner'], data: markets[i+1]['histories'].map{|h| [h['created_at'], 1/h['price']]}}
    ] %>
```

Which shows the first two series on the chart, but can't be the right way as there are different i elements for each chart.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using `.each` method. I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this, but it's working for now.

```
def chart(markets)
  chart_data = markets.map{ |m| [name: m['runner'], data: m['histories'].map{|h| [h['created_at'], 1/h['price']]}]}.flatten
  line_chart chart_data.each do |m| 
    [{name: [:name], data: [:data]}]
  end
end
```